# rightCalloutAccessoryView not shown on the MKPinAnnotationView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, mkmapview

I use the MKPinAnnotationView on the MKMapView, **the title and subtitle is shown normally**, but the `rightCalloutAccessoryView` is not shown.

I tried google a lot, but could not show it yet. My code is below.

```
- (void)addAnnotation
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate = self.location.coordinate;

    MapAnnotation *annotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:theCoordinate];
    annotation.title = @"Pin";
    annotation.subtitle = @"More information";

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapAnnotation class]]) {
        static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"MyMKPinAnnotationView";
        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

        if (!annotationView) {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
            annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
            annotationView.enabled = YES;
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        } else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Notice that title & subtitle can be shown.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `viewForAnnotation` isn't returning the `annotationView`. So make sure to return that (if it returns `nil`, the default behavior will take place, regardless of all of your work). See my revised answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seeing the title and subtitle is the default behavior of an annotation view. If you want to do anything else (such as the `rightCalloutAccessorView`), you have to make sure your `viewForAnnotation` is called by setting the `delegate` of your `MKMapView` and also make sure that your `viewForAnnotation` is returning the `annotationView` you're creating.

One of two problems is occurring:

1. Your `viewForAnnotation` is returning `nil` in all cases. Make sure you you return `annotationView` after creating/modifying it.
2. If your map view's `delegate` hasn't been set, your current `viewForAnnotation` would not be called at all.

   Make sure you have set the `delegate`. You can do this programmatically:

   ```
   self.mapView.delegate = self;
   ```

   Or you can do this in IB (by selecting the connections inspector, the rightmost tab of the right panel and <kbd>control</kbd>-drag from the `delegate` to the status bar of the scene):

   [image]

   If this is the case, if you put a `NSLog` statement or breakpoint in your `viewForAnnotation`. You might not see it being called at all if the `delegate` hasn't been set up properly.

Comment: Thank you! OMG... I was sleepy last night.